# Get Segmentation Fault when loading sample model face-detection-adas-0001.xml on openvino Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: openvino

When I run the sample, specifying the model and path to the input image:

```
./armv7l/Release/object_detection_sample_ssd -m ./open_model_zoo/tools/downloader/intel/face-detection-adas-0001/FP32/face-detection-adas-0001.xml -d MYRIAD -i test.jpg
```

There is a segmentation fault

```
[ INFO ] InferenceEngine: 
    IE version ......... 2021.4.2
    Build ........... 2021.4.2-3974-e2a469a3450-releases/2021/4
Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Files were added: 1
[ INFO ]     test.jpg
[ INFO ] Loading Inference Engine
[ INFO ] Device info: 
    MYRIAD
    myriadPlugin version ......... 2021.4.2
    Build ........... 2021.4.2-3974-e2a469a3450-releases/2021/4

[ INFO ] Loading network files:
[ INFO ] ./open_model_zoo/tools/downloader/intel/face-detection-adas-0001/FP32/face-detection-adas-0001.xml
[ INFO ] Preparing input blobs
[ INFO ] Batch size is 1
[ INFO ] Preparing output blobs
[ INFO ] Loading model to the device
Segmentation fault
```

I have searched everywhere, but there is no solution for this problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be resolved by adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a"` to `cmake` command when you build [Object Detection SSD C++ Sample](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_inference_engine_samples_object_detection_sample_ssd_README.html#object-detection-ssd-c-sample).

Build Object Detection SSD C++ Sample using the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a" /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/cpp

make -j2 object_detection_sample_ssd
```